# my get request does not work but changing it to a post works

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a `get` request that should return all of the logged-in user's project they created, I believe the code was written well. when I run it on postman I consistently get a `401 unauthorised` error, but when I change the request to patch for example, and I also run a `patch` request on the postman, it works properly. what could be the issue?

```
// get all logged in user's projects
router.get('/api/project/mine', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const id = req.user._id
        const projects = await Project.find({owner: id})
        res.status(200).send(projects)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(401).send()
    }
})
```

the auth middleware

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const User = require('../models/user')

const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '')
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'creativetoken')
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: decoded._id, 'tokens.token': token })

        if (!user) {
            throw new Error()
        }

        req.token = token
        req.user = user
        next()
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(401).send({ error: 'Please authenticate' })
    }
}

module.exports = auth
```

Note: the `auth` makes sure the objectId of the logged-in user is returned through `req.user.id`

Comment: Do you get any errors in your node js console?

Comment: Can you please show the auth middleware and the code of the client request?

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe no i dont get any error

Comment: @yochanansheinberger added the auth middleware

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 try-catch that return 401 but you don't log the error or return the error to frontend.
You need to add `console.log(e)` in 2 catch block in your `auth` middleware and your `get` request.

```
try { 
     // some of your code 
} catch (e) {
     console.log(e); //Add this line 
     res.status(401).send({ error: 'Please authenticate' })
}
```